# JSON summing multiple objects where values contain a string

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, sum

I'm using a d3.js based viz tool to graph data in real time.  I graph each series individually and I'd like to graph the sum as well.

How do I iterate through each object containing parser*, adding the y values so that `parserSum = 50`?

```
data = [
{
    "y": 20,
    "label": "parser1",
    "time": 1404999005
},
{
    "y": 30,
    "label": "parser2",
    "time": 1404999005
},
{
    "y": 15,
    "label": "reader1",
    "time": 1404999005
}]
```

**EDIT**
Using @juvian's answer, here is my final result:

http://jsfiddle.net/yeehawjared/u9Ppd/1/

```
var procs = ["parser", "reader", "writer"];
for (var i = 0; i < procs.length; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        var obj = data[x];
        if (obj.label.indexOf(procs[i]) != -1) {
            sum += obj.y;
        }
    }
    console.log(procs[i], sum)
}
```

Comment: Which is it... you don't know how to loop, or to add. Or is it reading a substring, or accessing an object property. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Oh well. We might as well make this interesting by giving an ECMAScript 6 solution: `res = [o.y for (o of data) if (o.label.startsWith("parser"))].reduce(function(a,b) { return a+b }, 0)`

Comment: well, I was trying to go along the lines of using d3.keys() and d3.values(), iterating through to find where key contains "parser".  I was stuck looping and finding substring.  Thanks for your comment, even though its over my head, and doesn't seem to work in jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to check if the label constains parser with indexOf and then sum that

```
var sum=0;
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var obj=data[i];
    if(obj.label.indexOf("parser") != -1){
        sum+=obj.y;
    }
}
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: you rock, thank you so much.  This works.  Will rate as correct answer after a day or so

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `.reduce` method on the array. It would look like this:

```
var sum = data.reduce(function(lastValue, currentElement){
  return currentElement.label.indexOf('parser') !== -1 ?
    lastValue + currentElement.y : 0;
}, 0);
```

Comment: yep, works great too.  Never used reduce, thanks for the example